# How to test Pinterest SDK locally?

Tags: javascript, sdk, pinterest

I'm testing out the Pinterest SDK on my local machine. The problem is, I need a secure server in order to test the API (they only allow Redirect URIs with a HTTPS prefix).

Every time I try to login to the Pinterest application it throws the error:

{"status": "failure", "message": "You are not permitted to access that resource.", "code": 7, "data": "The provided redirect_uri http://localhost:3000/ does not match any of the registered redirect URIs."}

Is there any way I can test via HTTPS locally?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Create React App you can start the development server in HTTPS, see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-https-in-development

Comment: I know this is late, but this is exactly what I did to get this to work, it's a very easy fix and just requires adding another line of code when building.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Pinterest demands that you have https link.

I tried using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to convert my localhost link to an https link for testing. But it was throwing some errors, so skipped it. You can try it out though

But if you wish to have a temporary setup to work with the APIs, lets say to write down functions to process information you get from APIs, which was my requirement, then you can follow what I did. May not be the best option, but I could get my job done.

I hosted a basic app on firebase. Firebase provides some [sample apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/) which you can use as base app if you want.

Just get the link of the hosted app and add it in your app page in  Pinterest.